# Array OutOfBounds Exception with MergeSort

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, mergesort

I am doing a simple MergeSort implementation taking it form a pseudocode. I use Java Generics for that purpose. However I get such exception on the last element in the first for-loop. I have already made some changes (hope for the better) but still this one inevitably comes up. Why is that so?

```
private Comparable[] mergesort(Comparable[] elements, int l, int r) {
    if(l < r){
        int m = (l + r - 1)/2;
        mergesort(elements, l, m);
        mergesort(elements, m + 1, r);
        int i = l;
        int j = m + 1;
        int k = l;
        Comparable[] elements1 = (Comparable[])new Comparable[l + r]; //changed from [l + r - 1] and in the function caller also mergesort(elements, elements.length - elements.length, elements.length - 1)
        while(i <= m && j <= r){
            if(elements[i].compareTo(elements[j]) <= 0 ){ 
                elements1[k] = elements[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                elements1[k] = elements[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;  
        }
        for(int h = i; i <= m; h++){
            elements[k + (h - i)] = elements[h];
            //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4(the length of the input array)
        }
        for(int h = j; h <= k - 1; h++){
            elements[h] = elements1[h];
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: what does this have to do with generics?

Comment: Where is it failing ? What are l, r, i, j, k, m... ?

Comment: @dotvav l - most left element(first), r - most right element (last), m - middle-element, i, j, k are needed for the iteration and the additional help-array. It is commented where the exception takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code is hard to read, I think you are comparing the wrong value.

```
  for(int h = i; i <= m; h++){
                 ^
                should be h
                elements[k + (h - i)] = elements[h];
                //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4(the length of the input array)


 }
```

Comment: I lost at least an hour looking for this one ... Thanks!! Sometimes you just need a second opinion.

Comment: @user4325010 It happens, also next time try to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You use:

```
for(int h = i; i <= m; h++) {
    elements[k + (h - i)] = elements[h];
}
```

You always increase `h` but compare `i <= m`. Since you never change `i` you have an endless loop.